# WSUS Package Publisher "kills" quote from properties

Tags: windows, windows-installer

We use WSUS Package Publisher to deploy "Data Loss Prevention" to our Windows 10 clients. We entered the properties (optional command line in WSUSPP) in the form PROPERTYNAME1="value1" PROPERTYNAME2="value2", but in WindowsUpdate.log the "MSI final command line" is missing the first quote (PROPERTYNAME1=value1" ...) and therefore the installation fails with code 0x80070667 (Bad command line).
And yes, the quotes are necessary because one property is a path with blanks.
When entering three quotes as opener to the first value, the final command line shows one opening quote, but there is an additional quote added at the end of the property string.

Is there a way to mask the quotes or the blanks? Or use an other string terminator? Or are we missing something else?

*EDIT*
Used the ORCA-utility as @Stein Asmul suggested and generated a new MSI file containing the requested properties. The final MSI command line now shows as

```
MSI final command line: /q ALLUSERS=1 MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL=Disable REBOOT=REALLYSUPPRESS
```

in the windows update log.
But still the install failes with error MSI result = 0x80070667 (ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND_LINE)

Comment: Can you use a transform? [An MST file](https://community.broadcom.com/symantecenterprise/communities/community-home/librarydocuments/viewdocument?DocumentKey=4d3b74ae-f896-488f-8923-9a4c192b0028&CommunityKey=1ecf5f55-9545-44d6-b0f4-4e4a7f5f5e68&tab=librarydocuments)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of Stein Asmul led to the final solution:

- Downloaded Orca.exe (Utility to create Transform-Files)
- Created a *.MST File and added all properties previously set at command line as rows to the property-table
- Added the *.MST File to the package in WSUS PP